# Can I fetch a stash from a remote repo into a local branch?

Tags: git, git-stash

A colleague has a stash in their repository which I can access (via the filesystem), and I'd like to pull that stash into a branch in my repository.

```
% git ls-remote ~alice/work/repo/ stash
3ccc82fb1ee0e7bde1250c7926d333ce21c109c0        refs/stash
```

But when I try to fetch that, git tells me "unable to find 3cc82..."

```
% git fetch ~alice/work/repo stash:new_branch
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to find 3ccc82fb1ee0e7bde1250c7926d333ce21c109c0
fatal: object 3ccc82fb1ee0e7bde1250c7926d333ce21c109c0 not found
```

Is there a way I can fetch the remote stash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: A direct answer to the original poster's question is:

```
git send-pack ./ 3ccc82fb1ee0e7bde1250c7926d333ce21c109c0:refs/heads/tempbranch
```

'tempbranch' will be at the *latest* stash (stash@{0}) from the remote. Unfortunately I don't think the reflog is fetched from remote branches, so there is no way to get at the other stashes, unless you have access to the source repo.

**Scripting it**: I posted a more comprehensive 'scripted' solution over at the mentioned question

[Is it possible to push a git stash to a remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository/5248758#5248758)

Also, as I discovered in the meantime, git-send-pack can be instrumental if you have access to the source repo:

```
git send-pack ../myworkingfolder/ stash@{0}:refs/heads/collegue_stash
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that (and upvoted it). However this question is trying to solve a different problem; I could see the remote repo but my colleague had stashed instead of committed, then gone home and told me about the stash, so I just wanted to grab that stash. A couple of longer winded solutions present themselves (e.g. make a patch and apply it locally) but I was looking for a direct way to fetch the stash into my repo.

Comment: Edited comment with more insights

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can, partially. The [stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) is just another [ref](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References). You can fetch refs which are not heads (branches) by specifying a [refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) with the full ref path.

```
git fetch some-remote +refs/stash:refs/remotes/some-remote/stash
git stash apply some-remote/stash
```

You can configure this up to fetch the stash when you run an ordinary fetch, too:

```
git config --add remote.some-remote.fetch +refs/stash:refs/remotes/some-remote/stash
git fetch some-remote
git stash apply some-remote/stash
```

But this will fail if there is no stash with a "Invalid refspec" as the ref doesn't exist, so you're probably better off doing it on demand. You could set up an alias like:

```
cat > /usr/local/bin/git-fetch-stash
git fetch --verbose "$1" +refs/stash:refs/remotes/"$1"/stash 
^D
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-fetch-stash

git fetch-stash some-remote
```

The caveat is that you cannot fetch multiple stashes. These are stored as entries in the [reflog](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery), and you cannot fetch a remote's reflog.

Answer (score 0):

You can't but this provides you an alternate path.
[is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository)

Comment: Hi naven87. I did see that other SO question but it didn't suit what I needed. Thanks for your answer, and I will accept it after a while if no-one else posts a more direct solution.