# Git: Compare All Local Commits to Remote Repo Version

Tags: git, diff, compare, status, gitk

I'm somewhat new to Git and what I'm trying to do seems like it should be possible. Basically I've been working off of clone of a repo and have made quite a few local commits. Is there a way to see the diff of the 'sum' of all my changes and the original repo version? I would assume this would be possible because Git will essentially do this when I do a `push`.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: in gitk I will see something like this:
* - [mybranch] Added '42' to end of answers.txt  (local commit)
* - Added 'Hello World' to end of my.txt (local commit)
* - Added 'C#/.NET' to beginning of my.txt (local commit)
* - <[RemoteRepo]> (original repo I cloned from)

How is it I can view the difference of the sum of all my changes to `my.txt` and `answers.txt` when compared to the original version I checked out from `RemoteRepo`?

Comment: If you need to do this in GitHub - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838096/820410)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are three ways ( two others from other answers given here )

```
1) git diff origin/master master
2) git diff origin/master..master
3) git diff origin/master...master
```

First one and second one are same and show changes between the tips of the master and remote master.

Third one shows changes that occurred on the master since branch last push and I think this is the most appropriate one you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, 3 worked great (I ended up using git difftool instead of git diff). 1 and 2 showed differences that were not mine on the remote repo so those were not what I needed.

Comment: `origin/master...origin/master` is an empty set? I think you somehow messed up the syntax during editing. Did you mean `origin/master...master` instead?

Comment: does this command open vi/vim? I am so confused as to what happens after the command, what environment am I in??

Comment: Does the master branch need to be the branch currently checkout out?

Answer (score 17):

The most ready answer is

```
 git show-branch
```

What you can do for more control is is use `git log` annex `git rev-list`:

```
 git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick \
      --oneline branchname...remote/branchname
```

This is my preferred method and will result in something like

```
> | fff6bda remote fix
< | c8903ee local fix
< |   724373c Merge branch 'bla' into bla
|\ \  
| < | 2faf547 details
| < | abbdc47 ....
|/ /  
< | befc181 some tagged commit
```

Include --decorate and you'll get something close to gitk, git-gui and gitweb:

```
> | fff6bda remote fix
< | c8903ee local fix
< |   724373c (tag_4) Merge branch 'bla' into bla
|\ \  
| < | 2faf547 details
| < | abbdc47 ....
|/ /  
< | befc181 (tag_3) some tagged commit
```

#### PRO TIP 1: *Use '`git config alias.lr log --long-option1 --long-option2`' for convenient use*

#### PRO TIP 2: *Use '`git config color.ui auto`' for immediate eye-relief*

If you wanted *all* local heads (*on all local branches*) versus *all* remote commits (*on ditto branches*):

```
git log --decorate --pretty=oneline --all --not --glob=refs/remotes --no-walk
```

Leave off the no-walk to get all individual revisions. In this case I prefer to use the switches shown earlier (--graph --left-right)

### Merges

If you want to see merges clearly, include --boundary

### Various advanced queries:

#### Filtering the results

Git `log` and `rev-list` support a whole slew of cunning filtering ability, see the man page

```
--after '2001-01-01'
--until 'last week'
--author 'martin'
-E -i  --grep='fixes #[0123456789]+'
-S 'new_debug_function'
```

and many, many others. This should give you plenty of leverage to get exactly at the info you want with almost zero effort

#### What's stashed locally?

What resides in stashes, but not on remotes (note there is no way to refer to stashes on remote braches because stashes reside in reflogs, and the reflogs (even for remote branches) always reflect local history[1]):

```
git log $(git rev-list -g stash) --not --glob=refs/remotes
```

#### All (other) unreachable commits...

Notes

- on my workflow these constitue rebased/amended commits and dropped stashes only
- also generating these will take some time depending on the size of your history graph
- this will include any dropped stashes, but not the current stashes

  git log $(git fsck --unreachable --full  --lost-found |
                grep ' commit ' | cut -d' ' -f3) \
      --no-walk --not --glob=refs/remotes --oneline --decorate

### Scripting

For scripting purposes, replace the use of `git log` with `git rev-list` and you'll get just the hashes (and some more script-prrof robustness)

[1] See also my prior answer(s) on how to transfer stashes between repos:

- [Is it possible to push a git stash to a remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository/5248758#5248758)
- [Can I fetch a stash from a remote repo into a local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/can-i-fetch-a-stash-from-a-remote-repo-into-a-local-branch/5257371#5257371)

Answer (score 13):

The simplest and certainly easiest to remember command that (usually) does what you want is this:

```
git diff origin
```

This shows the diff between what you originally pulled (the origin) and the current branch you're working on, which defaults to `master`.

Answer (score 5):

the difference can be viewed with `git diff A B`, it will compare the code in A to B:

```
git diff origin/master master
```

`origin/master` is the state of the remote master branch when you last fetched (or cloned) from it, `master` is the local state of the code – unless you switched branches when working locally.

Answer (score 3):

for everything
 git diff HEAD origin/"nameofyourbranch"

for specific file 
 git diff HEAD:"filename" origin/"nameofbranch":"filename"

Comment: or `git diff origin/branch HEAD -- file`

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff origin/master..master
```