# What is git trying to push?

Tags: git

I want to delete my repo but I want to make sure all my changesets have been pushed. `git log origin..HEAD` and `git log origin/master..master` both show nothing.  However, when I try `git push`, I get:

```
To remote-repo
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '/van/work/nms/esteras/cmpt-bitArray-clean1.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

If I have no local changes shouldn't it just say `Everything up-to-date`?  If I have outgoing changes how can I tell what they are?  I may not care about them but I need to know what they are to decide.

Comment: check difference with origin after doing a git fetch

Comment: you should `$ git pull` first

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when the remote site has changes, or (worse) has been *rebased* (what is known as an operation rewriting history).

You can find the difference between your local HEAD (master) and the remote using this method:

- [Git: Compare All Local Commits to Remote Repo Version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5734722/85371)

Comment: `git diff origin/master...master` is returning no output but I still get the error.

Comment: @StephenRasku I think you missed [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5734957/85371) there. It is entirely possible to have _identical content_ with a _different_ history (e.g. after rebase, squash, merge etc.). This can lead to an 'incompatible' branch, where you'd have to merge or force the push. Look at `git log (options) origin/master...master` instead for differences in the revision ancestry!

Comment: `git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline origin...origin/master` and `git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline origin/master...origin` both return no output.

Comment: First, `...` is _commutative_ (A...B is equivalent to B...A). Second: that is surprising. I can only _guess_ somehow you (a) are not locally up-to-date (`git remote update -prune`?) OR (b) are pushing to another branch/repository than you are comparing to.

Comment: ***Oh wait:*** (c) drop the `--cherry-pick` option in that log? It would show rebased commits as different, which is _exactly_ what you want to see here. This option is described in the man-page, or e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7549118/85371

Comment: I tried removing `--cherry-pick`.  It made no difference.  I did `update --prune`.  I am still unable to push.  I am pushing back to origin.  I even explicitly did `git push origin` and it still gives the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you want to be running `git diff origin/master` or `git diff origin/master..master`

`git diff origin/master...master` compares changes since your last push or rather changes that are in your local history that are not on the remote.

Comment: I want the list of changesets (i.e. `git log`) not the differences.  `git diff` will show me what changed but not why.

Comment: that is because you are seeing a common history with different data - this is entirely possible, so you want to check the diff for differences, log is not what changed or the differences, its a history  and a comparison of logs is just that a comparison of history.  If you want to see differences, use diff.

Comment: Like I said, I want the changesets not the diffs.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no changeset - that is the point.  You have a common history.  That is a common problem with force pushes

Comment: I don't think I have a common history.  I am assuming you are talking about the same changesets with different hashes.  Is there a way to verify this? I don't see any evidence of this.