# How to fix stale git branch -r (delete phantom git branches)?

Tags: git

```
$ git branch
  develop
* feature/bug_76
  master
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/feature/implement_IBResponder
  origin/master
  origin/origin
  origin/sculptor_strategy
```

Locally, I am good.  I want to delete all the crud on origin so I try:

```
$ git push origin :origin/sculptor_strategy
error: unable to delete 'origin/sculptor_strategy': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab:pitbull.git'
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

(Wild Guess) Is some local cache of what's on origin stale?

**ANSWER**

It turned out to be a red-herring - the problem was, my local cache was stale, as I suspected.  Both answers below will work fine.

Comment: Have you tried `git push origin :sculptor_strategy`?

Comment: y to both - same error message : `remote ref does not exist`

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382999/so-many-unused-branches-how-to-cleanup/14384603#14384603

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and in GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-in-github)

Comment: maybe the remote branch is already deleted? do `git fetch origin` and see.

Comment: @mvp +1 for a v.useful post - but does that mean I cannot cleanup/delete what's on origin?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: it is not necessarily duplicate. OP may want to delete something that he shouldn't

Comment: Also possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751582/fetch-from-origin-with-deleted-remote-branches

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Fetching alone will not help. He will need to fetch with the prune option, otherwise the deleted refs will not be deleted locally.

Comment: @pmr `git fetch -p` was the correct answer - add it as an answer and I will accept - TYVM.

Comment: WARNING: the link added above **This question may already have an answer here:** actually obfuscates the problem.  Look at the answers below for clear solutions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are probably not fetching with the prune option enabled. Use: `git fetch --prune`.

Answer (score 23):

Use:

```
git remote prune origin
```

to drop references that are already removed remotely.  Or:

```
git fetch -p origin
```

which does the same thing, or:

```
git remote update --prune
```

(I'm not really sure why there are so many ways to do this.  They *should* all act the same, but in at least some versions of git, sometimes one will work and another won't, so if one form does not work it may help to try another.)