# How to delete a phantom Git reference?

Tags: git

I have a Git branch that should have been deleted, but it is still visible for most git commands (e.g. `git show phantom`).

`git show-ref phantom` doesn't find the reference

`git log --decorate --max-count=1 phantom` finds the reference, but doesn't show any branches or tags on the commit.

`git fsck` list a bunch of dangling objects, but nothing else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix stale git branch -r (delete phantom git branches)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786786/how-to-fix-stale-git-branch-r-delete-phantom-git-branches)

Comment: @Joe that question was about remote-tracking branches, my branch is (was) local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to delete the reference with

```
git update-ref -d phantom
```

I was stumped by the fact that it didn't show up either as a branch or as a tag, but I guess `git-update-ref` doesn't care about such trifles.