# What is my bottleneck when cloning a git repository from a virtual machine with a fast network connection?

Tags: git, performance, vmware, git-clone

I have a situation with a relatively large git repository located in a virtual machine on an elderly, slow host on my local network where it takes quite a while to do the initial clone.

```
ravn@bamboo:~/git$ git clone gitosis@gitbox:git00
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ravn/git/git00/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 89973, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (26745/26745), done.
remote: Total 89973 (delta 50970), reused 85013 (delta 47798)
Receiving objects: 100% (89973/89973), 349.86 MiB | 2.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (50970/50970), done.
Checking out files: 100% (11722/11722), done.
ravn@bamboo:~/git$
```

There is no git specific configuration changes in gitosis.

Is there any way of speeding up the receiving bit up to what the network is capable of?

---

I need the new repositories to be properly connected with the upstream repository.  To my understanding, this requires git to do the cloning, and thus raw bit copying outside of git will not work.

Comment: `and thus raw bit copying outside of git will not work` - will you please provide source for that claim? It seems wrong to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After realizing that the upper limit to the transfer speed of data, is the ssh connection which is established "outside" of git I did some experiments, and found that the upper limit of using pcsp (Putty scp) was 3,0 MB/s as the blowfish encryption scheme was properly chosen.  A control experiment with raw ftp showed that the transfer speed was 3.1 MB/s, so it indicated that this was the upper bound of the network.

This runs inside a vmware hypervisor, and as the process doing network I/O utilized almost 100% cpu it indicated that the bottleneck was the Ubuntu network card driver.  I then found that even though vmware tools were installed, for some reason the kernel still used the vlance driver (emulating a 10 MBps network card with IRQ's and all) instead of the vmxnet driver (which speaks directly to the hypervisor).  This now awaits a service window to be changed.

In other words, the problem was not with git but the underlying "hardware".

Answer (score 32):

> **PS**. Fair warning:
>
> `git` is generally considered blazingly fast. You should try cloning a full repo from darcs, bazaar, hg (god forbid: TFS or subversion...). Also, if you routinely clone full repos from scratch, you'd be doing something wrong anyway. You can always just `git remote update` and get incremental changes.
>
> For various other ways to keep *full* repos in synch see, e.g.
>
> - ["fetch --all" in a git bare repository doesn't synchronize local branches to the remote ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559321/fetch-all-in-a-git-bare-repository-doesnt-synchronize-local-branches-to-the/5559586#5559586)
> - [How to update a git clone --mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150188/how-to-update-a-git-clone-mirror/6151901#6151901)
>
> (The contain links to other relevant SO posts)

#### Dumb copy

As mentioned you could just copy a repository with 'dumb' file transfer.

This will certainly not waste time compressing, repacking, deltifying and/or filtering.

Plus, you will get

- hooks
- config (remotes, push branches, settings (whitespace, merge, aliases, user details etc.)
- stashes <sub><sup>(see [Can I fetch a stash from a remote repo into a local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/can-i-fetch-a-stash-from-a-remote-repo-into-a-local-branch/5257371#5257371) also)</sup></sub>
- rerere cache
- reflogs
- backups (from filter-branch, e.g.) and various other things (intermediate state from rebase, bisect etc.)

This may or may *not* be what you require, but it is nice to be aware of the fact

---

#### Bundle

Git clone by default optimizes for bandwidth. Since git clone, by default, does not *mirror* all branches (see `--mirror`) it would not make sense to just dump the pack-files as-is (because that will send possibly way more than required).

When distributing to a *truly big* number of clients, **consider using *bundles*.**

If you want a fast clone without the server-side cost, the *git way* is `bundle create`. You can now distribute the bundle, without the server even being involved. If you mean that `bundle... --all` includes more than simple `git clone`, consider e.g. `bundle ... master` to reduce the volume.

```
git bundle create snapshot.bundle --all # (or mention specific ref names instead of --all)
```

and distribute the snapshot bundle instead. That's the best of both worlds, while of course you won't get the items from the bullet list above. On the receiving end, just

```
git clone snapshot.bundle myclonedir/
```

#### Compression configs

You can look at lowering server load by reducing/removing compression. 
Have a look at these config settings (I assume `pack.compression` may help you lower the server load)

> #### <sup>core.compression</sup>
>
> An integer -1..9, indicating a default compression level. -1 is the zlib default. 0 means no compression, and 1..9 are various speed/size tradeoffs, 9 being slowest. If set, this provides a default to other compression variables, such as
>   core.loosecompression and pack.compression.
>
> #### <sup>core.loosecompression</sup>
>
> An integer -1..9, indicating the compression level for objects that are not in a pack file. -1 is the zlib default. 0 means no compression, and 1..9 are various speed/size tradeoffs, 9 being slowest. If not set, defaults to
>   core.compression. If that is not set, defaults to 1 (best speed).
>
> #### <sup>pack.compression</sup>
>
> An integer -1..9, indicating the compression level for objects in a pack file. -1 is the zlib default. 0 means no compression, and 1..9 are various speed/size tradeoffs, 9 being slowest. If not set, defaults to core.compression. If that
>   is not set, defaults to -1, the zlib default, which is "a default compromise between speed and compression (currently equivalent to level 6)."
>
> Note that changing the compression level will not automatically recompress all existing objects. You can force recompression by passing the -F option to git-repack(1).

Given ample network bandwidth, this *will* in fact result in faster clones. **Don't forget about `git-repack -F` when you decide to benchmark that!**

Comment: Thanks.  I like the résult of "git clone" - I just want to know how to speed that up.  suggestions for that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen not sure what you're asking. But let me add that you can just clone from the bundle after you copied/mailed it around: `git clone snapshot.bundle` will clone into a new `snapshot` repo :)

Comment: I want the actual cloning process to happen faster than it does today, and just that.  It does what I need, it is just slower than it can be, and if it just requires tuning a parameter it would be nice.

Comment: You ask a question, then you are liable to get the answers to that. _If you can accept that you get answers you were not hoping for it would be nice_ (You can dream about options to `git clone`, but it's not my fault that they don't exist). I've **updated** my answer with more background info

Comment: I've written my thoughts on the matter in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5151/room-for-sehe-and-thorbjorn-ravn-andersen

Comment: `(god forbid: TFS or subversion...)` made me laugh. Good old days.

Comment: @Kamath TFS "merge days" or "exclusive lockouts so nobody has to merge"? *sighs*

Answer (score 32):

Use the depth to create a shallow clone.

```
git clone --depth 1 <repository>
```

Comment: For local repos: warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead.. Using file:// fatal: Unable to create temporary file '<repo>/shallow_cTG1x2': Permission denied

Comment: Note that this is not always faster, I have seen repositories where shallow cloning is slower than a full clone since git on the server side spends a lot of time figuring out what to send.

Comment: FWIW this was not faster for a medium sized project, with fairly small history, cloned from github, with git 2.20

Answer (score 7):

The `git clone --depth=1 ...` [suggested in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24087074/6309) will become faster in Q2 2019 with Git 2.22.
That is because, during an initial "`git clone --depth=...`" partial clone, it is
pointless to spend cycles for a large portion of the connectivity
check that enumerates and skips promisor objects (which by definition is all objects fetched from the other side).
This has been optimized out.

> ### `clone`: do faster object check for partial clones

> For partial clones, doing a full connectivity check is wasteful; we skip
> promisor objects (which, for a partial clone, is all known objects), and
> enumerating them all to exclude them from the connectivity check can
> take a significant amount of time on large repos.
>
> At most, we want to make sure that we get the objects referred to by any
> wanted refs.
> For partial clones, just check that these objects were transferred.
>
> Result:
>
> ```
>  Test                          dfa33a2^         dfa33a2
>  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  5600.2: clone without blobs   18.41(22.72+1.09)   6.83(11.65+0.50) -62.9%
>  5600.3: checkout of result    1.82(3.24+0.26)     1.84(3.24+0.26) +1.1%
> ```
>
> 62% faster!

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), an unneeded connectivity check is now disabled in a partial clone when fetching into it.

See [commit 2df1aa2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df1aa239cd50698ab3e0c2cb18b9c1d2f0e44d7), [commit 5003377](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50033772d50ef3c4023d63561d20bc61db96500e) (12 Jan 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8fb3945](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fb39450371ce9a89e0f551c94f02e73819f8325), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`connected`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50033772d50ef3c4023d63561d20bc61db96500e): verify promisor-ness of partial clone
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>

> Commit [dfa33a298d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfa33a298de2ab724d4812633bb009a90d1df790) ("`clone`: do faster object check for partial clones", 2019-04-21, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b51f0d38d24a21dc69a53e972497928183d399e)) optimized the connectivity check done when cloning with `--filter` to check only the existence of objects directly pointed to by refs.
> But this is not sufficient: they also need to be promisor objects.
> Make this check more robust by instead checking that these objects are promisor objects, that is, they appear in a promisor pack.

And:

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df1aa239cd50698ab3e0c2cb18b9c1d2f0e44d7): forgo full connectivity check if `--filter`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
>
> If a filter is specified, we do not need a full connectivity check on the contents of the packfile we just fetched; we only need to check that the objects referenced are promisor objects.
>
> This significantly speeds up fetches into repositories that have many promisor objects, because during the connectivity check, all promisor objects are enumerated (to mark them UNINTERESTING), and that takes a significant amount of time.

---

And, still with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), The object reachability bitmap machinery and the partial cloning machinery were not prepared to work well together, **because some object-filtering criteria that partial clones use inherently rely on object traversal, but the bitmap machinery is an optimization to bypass that object traversal**.

> There however are some cases where they can work together, and they were taught about them.

See [commit 20a5fd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20a5fd881a98cfe153fa5a81754994c7046a6e41) (18 Feb 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 3ab3185](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ab3185f999f5d0d0079ac8246edb8fca5d9d3fd), [commit 84243da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84243da1298890bd7370df66b754c2b252a08346), [commit 4f3bd56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3bd5606a02260274555f41fd7d6368f2bea1d8), [commit cc4aa28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc4aa28506e079e0c17cfbe78743530795803ea8), [commit 2aaeb9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2aaeb9ac414d75f875efa968480db1ce85dc8dc5), [commit 6663ae0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6663ae0a0818aba5d4de289b1a37e1961ad6c367), [commit 4eb707e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4eb707ebd681eb85306071db33ed70186d1642ac), [commit ea047a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea047a8eb4f45c1c4e3c9b1af919bf0361ac1b7c), [commit 608d9c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/608d9c93658d6ec2d585748ed45218cc1f404640), [commit 55cb10f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55cb10f9b5cd7216652a5879b792bcd7ac173035), [commit 792f811](https://github.com/git/git/commit/792f8119986bd354eb4ea0858dfd45904120c257), [commit d90fe06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d90fe06ea7dd15bdbd555ad2f4bfdd069032b697) (14 Feb 2020), and [commit e03f928](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e03f928e2ab92e47467d48520a73a19582dff286), [commit acac50d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acac50dd8c2c9725841b3e9143d78c6345dc076c), [commit 551cf8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/551cf8b655fa73c90dabea633d41b5f10deffaf2) (13 Feb 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0df82d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0df82d99dae85dbd4f667e95020a146ea0167975), 02 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pack-bitmap`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84243da1298890bd7370df66b754c2b252a08346): implement `BLOB_LIMIT` filtering
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Just as the [previous commit implemented `BLOB_NONE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667992/6309), we can support `BLOB_LIMIT` filters by looking at the sizes of any blobs in the result and unsetting their bits as appropriate.
> This is slightly more expensive than `BLOB_NONE,` but still produces a noticeable speedup (these results are on [git.git](https://github.com/git/git)):
>
> ```
> Test                                         HEAD~2            HEAD
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 5310.9:  rev-list count with blob:none       1.80(1.77+0.02)   0.22(0.20+0.02) -87.8%
> 5310.10: rev-list count with blob:limit=1k   1.99(1.96+0.03)   0.29(0.25+0.03) -85.4%
> ```
>
> The implementation is similar to the `BLOB_NONE` one, with the exception that we have to go object-by-object while walking the blob-type bitmap (since we can't mask out the matches, but must look up the size individually for each blob).
> The trick with using `ctz64()` is taken from `show_objects_for_type()`, which likewise needs to find individual bits (but wants to quickly skip over big chunks without blobs).

---

Git 2.27 (Q2 2020) will simplify the commit ancestry connectedness check in a partial clone repository in which "promised" objects are assumed to be obtainable lazily on-demand from promisor remote repositories.

See [commit 2b98478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b98478c6fc32b04434981c783b0472e0137cfad) (20 Mar 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0c60105](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c601052a5f761fd9c207a56ae11789c8598e25d), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`connected`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b98478c6fc32b04434981c783b0472e0137cfad): always use partial clone optimization
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>

> With [50033772d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50033772d50ef3c4023d63561d20bc61db96500e) ("`connected`: verify promisor-ness of partial clone", 2020-01-30, Git v2.26.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fb39450371ce9a89e0f551c94f02e73819f8325) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ae7e234c7e75dace3ba8aa8d87166ac7d75d7dd)), the fast path (checking promisor packs) in `check_connected()` now passes a subset of the slow path (rev-list) > - if all objects to be checked are found in promisor packs, both the fast path and the slow path will pass;
>
> - otherwise, the fast path will definitely not pass.
>
> This means that we can always attempt the fast path whenever we need to do the slow path.
>
> The fast path is currently guarded by a flag; therefore, remove that flag.
> Also, make the fast path fallback to the slow path - if the fast path fails, the failing OID and all remaining OIDs will be passed to rev-list.
>
> **The main user-visible benefit is the performance of fetch from a partial clone - specifically, the speedup of the connectivity check done before the fetch.**
> In particular, a no-op fetch into a partial clone on my computer was sped up from 7 seconds to 0.01 seconds. This is a complement to the work in [2df1aa239c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df1aa239cd50698ab3e0c2cb18b9c1d2f0e44d7) ("`fetch`: forgo full connectivity check if --filter", 2020-01-30, Git v2.26.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fb39450371ce9a89e0f551c94f02e73819f8325) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ae7e234c7e75dace3ba8aa8d87166ac7d75d7dd)), which is the child of the aforementioned [50033772d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50033772d50ef3c4023d63561d20bc61db96500e). In that commit, the connectivity check *after* the fetch was sped up.
>
> The addition of the fast path might cause performance reductions in these cases:
>
> - If a partial clone or a fetch into a partial clone fails, Git will fruitlessly run `rev-list` (it is expected that everything fetched would go into promisor packs, so if that didn't happen, it is most likely that rev-list will fail too).
> - Any connectivity checks done by receive-pack, in the (in my opinion, unlikely) event that a partial clone serves receive-pack.
>
> I think that these cases are rare enough, and the performance reduction in this case minor enough (additional object DB access), that the benefit of avoiding a flag outweighs these.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the object walk with object filter "`--filter=tree:0`" can now take advantage of the pack bitmap when available.

See [commit 9639474](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9639474b6dd126bae29dba70e2fbe11169d60e20), [commit 5bf7f1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bf7f1eaa51b3f35161e1c9e4d8bc843330dea3c) (04 May 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit b0a8d48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a8d4820baa9966511ea9bd8c8b09dab087475f), [commit 856e12c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/856e12c18a4616bbfbdfd1777577c1182b148519) (04 May 2020) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 69ae8ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69ae8ffa2a011384d317891c256aa6d381b003cd), 13 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pack-bitmap.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a8d4820baa9966511ea9bd8c8b09dab087475f): support 'tree:0' filtering
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> In the previous patch, we made it easy to define other filters that exclude all objects of a certain type. Use that in order to implement bitmap-level filtering for the '`--filter=tree:<n>`' filter when '`n`' is equal to `0`.
>
> The general case is not helped by bitmaps, since for values of '`n > 0`', the object filtering machinery requires a full-blown tree traversal in order to determine the depth of a given tree.
> Caching this is non-obvious, too, since the same tree object can have a different depth depending on the context (e.g., a tree was moved up in the directory hierarchy between two commits).
>
> But, the '`n = 0`' case can be helped, and this patch does so.
> Running `p5310.11` in this tree and on master with the kernel, we can see that this case is helped substantially:
>
> ```
> Test                                  master              this tree
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 5310.11: rev-list count with tree:0   10.68(10.39+0.27)   0.06(0.04+0.01) -99.4%
> ```

And:

See [commit 9639474](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9639474b6dd126bae29dba70e2fbe11169d60e20), [commit 5bf7f1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bf7f1eaa51b3f35161e1c9e4d8bc843330dea3c) (04 May 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit b0a8d48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a8d4820baa9966511ea9bd8c8b09dab087475f), [commit 856e12c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/856e12c18a4616bbfbdfd1777577c1182b148519) (04 May 2020) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 69ae8ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69ae8ffa2a011384d317891c256aa6d381b003cd), 13 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pack-bitmap`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9639474b6dd126bae29dba70e2fbe11169d60e20): pass object filter to fill-in traversal
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Sometimes a bitmap traversal still has to walk some commits manually, because those commits aren't included in the bitmap packfile (e.g., due to a push or commit since the last full repack).
>
> If we're given an object filter, we don't pass it down to this traversal.
> It's not necessary for correctness because the bitmap code has its own filters to post-process the bitmap result (which it must, to filter out the objects that *are* mentioned in the bitmapped packfile).
>
> And with blob filters, there was no performance reason to pass along those filters, either. The fill-in traversal could omit them from the result, but it wouldn't save us any time to do so, since we'd still have to walk each tree entry to see if it's a blob or not.
>
> But now that we support tree filters, there's opportunity for savings. A `tree:depth=0` filter means we can avoid accessing trees entirely, since we know we won't them (or any of the subtrees or blobs they point to).
> The new test in `p5310` shows this off (the "partial bitmap" state is one where `HEAD~100` and its ancestors are all in a bitmapped pack, but `HEAD~100..HEAD` are not).
>
> Here are the results (run against `linux.git`):
>
> ```
> Test                                                  HEAD^               HEAD
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [...]
> 5310.16: rev-list with tree filter (partial bitmap)   0.19(0.17+0.02)     0.03(0.02+0.01) -84.2%
> ```
>
> The absolute number of savings isn't *huge*, but keep in mind that we only omitted 100 first-parent links (in the version of `linux.git` here, that's 894 actual commits).
>
> In a more pathological case, we might have a much larger proportion of non-bitmapped commits. I didn't bother creating such a case in the perf script because the setup is expensive, and this is plenty to show the savings as a percentage.

---

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), handling of "promisor packs" that allows certain objects to be missing and lazily retrievable has been optimized (a bit).

See [commit c1fa951](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1fa951d7ea9e943f001ac7c7502995273db5776), [commit 45a187c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45a187cc34b5016842b91ef14b59e40505afff46), [commit fcc07e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcc07e980b344a813b47358d0aa823d07c7ac744) (13 Apr 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 13158b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13158b9910f8de4a88b39420be80f03c681b3ec9), 30 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`revision`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1fa951d7ea9e943f001ac7c7502995273db5776): avoid parsing with --exclude-promisor-objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When `--exclude-promisor-objects` is given, before traversing any objects we iterate over all of the objects in any promisor packs, marking them as UNINTERESTING and SEEN.
> We turn the oid we get from iterating the pack into an object with `parse_object()`, but this has two problems:
>
> - it's slow; we are zlib inflating (and reconstructing from deltas) every byte of every object in the packfile
> - it leaves the tree buffers attached to their structs, which means our heap usage will grow to store every uncompressed tree simultaneously.
>   This can be gigabytes.
>
> We can obviously fix the second by freeing the tree buffers after we've parsed them.
> But we can observe that the function doesn't look at the object contents at all! The only reason we call `parse_object()` is that we need a "`struct object`" on which to set the flags.
> There are two options here:
>
> - we can look up just the object type via `oid_object_info()`, and then call the appropriate `lookup_foo()` function
> - we can call `lookup_unknown_object()`, which gives us an `OBJ_NONE` struct (which will get auto-converted later by `object_as_type()` via calls to `lookup_commit()`, etc).
>
> The first one is closer to the current code, but we do pay the price to look up the type for each object.
> The latter should be more efficient in CPU, though it wastes a little bit of memory (the "unknown" object structs are a union of all object types, so some of the structs are bigger than they need to be).
> It also runs the risk of triggering a latent bug in code that calls `lookup_object()` directly but isn't ready to handle `OBJ_NONE` (such code would already be buggy, but we use `lookup_unknown_object()` infrequently enough that it might be hiding).
>
> I went with the second option here.
> I don't think the risk is high (and we'd want to find and fix any such bugs anyway), and it should be more efficient overall.
>
> The new tests in p5600 show off the improvement (this is on [git.git](https://github.com/git/git)):
>
> ```
> Test                                 HEAD^               HEAD
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 5600.5: count commits                0.37(0.37+0.00)     0.38(0.38+0.00) +2.7%
> 5600.6: count non-promisor commits   11.74(11.37+0.37)   0.04(0.03+0.00) -99.7%
> ```
>
> The improvement is particularly big in this script because *every* object in the newly-cloned partial repo is a promisor object.
> So after marking them all, there's nothing left to traverse.

---

An earlier optimization discarded a tree-object buffer that is still in use, which has been corrected with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022).

See [commit 1490d7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1490d7d82d5bd504b095c4db030a98b8080c596a) (14 Aug 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 01a30a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01a30a5a58053ce74a551a42d9edb2cf4f95632b), 25 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`is_promisor_object()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1490d7d82d5bd504b095c4db030a98b8080c596a): fix use-after-free of tree buffer
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Andrew Olsen</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Since [commit fcc07e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcc07e980b344a813b47358d0aa823d07c7ac744) (`is_promisor_object()`: free tree buffer after parsing, 2021-04-13, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13158b9910f8de4a88b39420be80f03c681b3ec9) listed in [batch #13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570)) `(is_promisor_object()`: free tree buffer after parsing, 2021-04-13), we'll always free the buffers attached to a "struct tree" after searching them for promisor links.
> But there's an important case where we don't want to do so: if somebody else is already using the tree!
>
> This can happen during a "`rev-list --missing=allow-promisor`" traversal in a partial clone that is missing one or more trees or blobs.
> Even a trivial use of "`--missing=allow-promisor`" triggers this problem, as the included test demonstrates (it's just a vanilla `--blob:none clone`).

Answer (score 4):

I'm bench marking git clone.

It can be faster with --jobs options if the project include submodules
ex:

```
git clone --recursive --shallow-submodules --depth 1 --branch "your tag or branch" --jobs 5 --  "your remote repo"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the log it seems you already finished the clone, if your problem is that you need to do this process multiple times on different machines, you can just copy the repository directory from one machine to the other. This way will preserve the relationship (remotes) between each copy and the repository you cloned from.

Comment: I do this very frequently, and I want the cloned repositories to be properly connected to the upstream repository.  Am I correct in assuming that this require a clone and cannot be done with a file copy?

Comment: If the upstream repository address is the same for all of your needed clones, then you can just copy the repository.

Comment: Yes, the copied repositories will be exactly like the one you had when you copied them, including local changes to the configuration and remote repository links (NOT including the global git configuration BTW, but so won't clone).
please accept my answer if it helped you...

Comment: Your answer did not help me.  I need a faster "git clone" for a moving target.

Comment: ok, new direction, if the compression is the problem I thinj you can avoid it by setting compression=0 in the config.core section. Not sure it will affect the transfer though.

Comment: By moving target you mean that the repository is updated all the time and you want the clones to be updated? in this case you can file copy from the last clone and just do a fetch on the new copy.

Comment: Yes, the repository is updated all the time and I want the clones to reflect this.  I have many different tasks, not all I can control, which all want to do their own "git clone".  Hence I need to optimize that process.

Comment: ok, so you can either file copy from the last created clone or from a clone that is created hourly or daily and the do fetch --all. just fetching the diff will make you configured, updated and should be faster in your case.