# Git large directory checkout fails

Tags: git

I used the procedure described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934) to clone a specific directory from a large git repository. Below are the commands I ran:

```
git clone --depth 1 --filter=blob:none --no-checkout [REPOSITORY]
git checkout master -- examples/
```

The `examples` directory has a lot (>1024) files and after downloading some of them, `git checkout master -- examples/` process terminated with the following error:

```
error: cannot create standard output pipe for index-pack: Too many open files
```

Can you help me diagnose and fix the issue? 
My Git version is `2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)`

Comment: There were a couple of bug fixes for problems in this area recently (around Git 2.24 or maybe even later). So, as [VonC suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61606467/1256452), it's a good idea to try upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Try first to see if the issue persists with Git 2.26.x, considering [`BLOB_NONE` filtering wasimplemented in 2.26](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667992/6309)

A lot of improvement are coming with [2.27 when it comes to partial cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56118819/6309)

In the meantime, you might have to use a [sparse checkout command (2.25)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309) to checkout only part of that huge folder.