# git fetch "unable to find" "object... not found" errors for stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I have a simple backup system where a git clone created using `--bare` (it might have been `--mirror`) run `git fetch` every hour. The idea is that if something happens to my working copies that I have a backup of my work in the clone.

This system works great, but I'm getting an error when I run `git fetch`:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to find 2a8c978c41c362c3f0c42775c9124780a0e71e08
fatal: object 2a8c978c41c362c3f0c42775c9124780a0e71e08 not found
```

When I look in the original repository for the object, it's a stash:

```
$ git show 2a8c978c41
commit 2a8c978c41c362c3f0c42775c9124780a0e71e08
Merge: 808f6e4 ddc28da
Author: Russell Silva <russell.silva@blahblah.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 29 10:19:26 2012
    WIP on experimental: 808f6e4 blah blah blah
```

It looks like the fetch is mostly successful; `git log <branch>` shows up-to-date branches. But the errors are pesky. How do I get rid of them? How do I keep them from recurring?

Note that this question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/can-i-fetch-a-stash-from-a-remote-repo-into-a-local-branch) where someone actually wants to fetch a stash. I don't care if my `git fetch` commands fetch stashes; it's fine if they don't.

EDIT: the full output of `git fetch --verbose` was requested:

```
$ git fetch --verbose
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
From /home/russell/work/russells-project
 = [up to date]      some-branch -> some-branch
error: unable to find 2a8c978c41c362c3f0c42775c9124780a0e71e08
fatal: object 2a8c978c41c362c3f0c42775c9124780a0e71e08 not found
```

I have changed names in the output to conceal private information and eliminated all but one of the "[up to date]" lines -- there's dozens of them, one for each branch in the repository.

Also, my remote is on the local filesystem; it's not being accessed over the network.

```
$ git remote --verbose
origin  /home/russell/work/russells-project (fetch)
origin  /home/russell/work/russells-project (push)
```

Comment: does it *always* fail when there's a stash? maybe a verbose output of `git fetch` would help, cause it's weird

Comment: @CharlesB: I'm not sure if it always fails with a stash; I'd have to do some more extensive testing. The supplied `git fetch` output is the total output of the command.

Comment: you can have more verbose output with `git fetch --verbose`

Comment: Also, what is the protocol? is it "raw file", or git://, or http://?

Comment: Something must somehow reference the stash. Have you tried a brute-force search for the stash's SHA1 in git's files or at least in .git/refs? Maybe that reveals the missing link.

Comment: How can we reproduce the error you're seeing without having access to your repo? Do you have steps we can follow to induce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using some 'cache_fu' http://github.com/defunkt/cache_fu.git