# Can I recover a GIT stash from a fetch

Tags: linux, git, git-stash, git-fetch

I've got a git repo, and my colleague had a clone of that on his PC. For whatever reason, we've lost his repository due to technical issues.

A short while before we lost his repo, he stashed some work, and I did a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge master`.

Is it possible to get the content of the stash? Would the `git fetch` command have pulled the stash over as well?

I can view all the remote branches with `git branch -a` but I need the stashed data.

We're running `git version 1.6.3.3` on `Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I don't believe you can recover from this. (arguably, if you could, it would be a security risk; someone might have stashed a password inside of a configuration file or something.)

From the documentation (`git fetch --help`): `Fetches named heads or tags from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete them.`

Key word: **named heads**. Sadly, the stash isn't a named head (or a tag).

Comment: Thanks for that, that explains it pretty well. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257371/197519 and this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/1550400/197519 also seem to state that you can't `fetch` stashes. I was being hopeful really.

Comment: // , Good answer. Would you mind including a link to a very brief explanation of what is (and, more relevant to this situation, what is **not**) a "named head" in Git bromenclature?

Comment: @NathanBasanese, I'm not sure I have a good answer, but a named head would be anything in `.git/refs/*/**`. Normally you'll see things like `heads` (your local branches), `remotes`, your remote branches, and `tags`. The stash is stored similarly, in `.git/refs/stash`, but `git` will not allow you to push it anywhere. It's not something you've given a name... you've just stashed some random work.