# How to connect a git stash url to my local repository to get an updated code each time?

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot, git-stash

I have created a search Directory project wherein I am searching for the table name in the codebase of my local. Now, I just want to connect this local repo to git stash so that each time it searches in the updated code and not the old one. How can we do this through java?

Please suggest

Comment: What is `git stash` here? It's not https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash, isn't it? Is it Atlassian Stash may be?

Comment: it is git only...i am trying to take a pull from git using java

Comment: So you want to fetch stashes from a remote repo? I'm not sure it's possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29839687/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1550378/7976758