# What is the most practical way to keep working on a git stash on a different computer?

Tags: git, copy, save, export, git-stash

it happened more than once to leave the office having only saved a stash of uncommitted code.

So, if I wanted to keep working on the same feature, I had to SSH to my host, create a disposable branch, commit the stash and push the new branch to the development repository.

Now I wonder if there is a cleaner, more practical solution for "copying/exporting" a git stash to another local repository. I have already ruled out SCP'ing the local repository on my office machine, because I could have some work in progress on my laptop, too.

P.S.: my question looks like the continuation of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git stash show` to make a patch and then `git apply` it on your home machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could save a patch and send that to yourself.

```
git diff > patchfile
```

Then you can apply it with...

```
git apply --stat patchfile
```

Comment: If I understand `format-patch` correctly, it assume the changes have already been committed. Isn't the question about uncommitted changes instead?

Comment: It is also my understanding. I confirm that I am talking about only uncommitted & stashed changes.

Comment: I will fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The stash is saved as a special type of commit, and so it **is** available in the git object database. But, the reference to that commit is outside of the namespace that is typically made available for fetching.

You could make the most recent stash available for fetching by running the following on the source repository:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/exported-stash refs/stash
```

This will create a branch named `exported-stash` which can be fetched like any other branch.  You can use a different name if you like, but avoid using `stash` since that will result in some annoying warnings about the name being ambiguous with the actual stash. After fetching from the remote it can be applied on another repository with:

```
git stash apply origin/exported-stash
```

(assuming that it was fetched from the remote `origin`).

After making changes you could even stash those locally and push the updated stash back to the origin with:

```
git push origin +stash:exported-stash
```

The `+` turns this into a forced push, but in this case that is actually safe.  The old version of the stash on the origin will just be moved to `stash@{1}` since the list of stashes is saved as a log of references.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Carl Norum, `git` can be used to create a patch. However, the command is a bit tricky. You'll need to call

`git diff stash@{0}^ stash@{0} > patch`

to create a patch (note that your shell may need you to wrap the stash's name in quotation marks). That creates a patch for all differences of your stash's parent and your stash itself.

Then, on your other machine, you can apply the patch with

`git apply patch`

Comment: In a discussion I could not really follow, I was told that it's different. Essentially, because `git stash show` treats commits as the merges they actually are. The proposed solution apparently does more suitable things. Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with those rather technical differences. I guess that for your purposes (in office: stash, create patch from stash; at home: patch and continue working), the solution should be identical. I am not sure though.

Comment: It looks like you could write a question about that :)

Comment: I guess I won't ask that question. Thinking about that workflow, a WIP throwaway branch seems best for me.