# How to compare .git directories so that I can delete one

Tags: git

I often work on the same project on several computers.  After some time, I need to make sure that the project files are synced and up to date with the latest changes on each computer.  So I end up with two directories, A and B, that have the same contents, but the .git files do not match between the two directories, even if their contents are the same.  I need to make sure that one directory (A) ends up with everything that B has, so that I can then delete B.

So I need a way to know that directory A/.git contains all the info that B/.git contains, even if the .git/* files do not compare.  Here is what I came up with:

(git branch -av;git stash show -v)|md5sum

If I run this in both A and B, I should get the same result if both sides have the same branches and stashes.  Is this sufficient to be sure that both repos have the same info?  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Uh, syncing between different PCs, ain't that the main goal of git.

Comment: What I am trying to avoid is overwriting one repo with another, and later realizing that I deleted a branch or something that only existed on the target PC.  Obviously syncing files is easy, but I like to know first what I will be destroying in the process.

Comment: Why overwrite though? Why not just `git fetch`?

Comment: I use git fetch all day.  I end up writing code on several computers over the week and do all kinds of stuff on each one, making/deleting branches and such.  At the end, I want to have one backup that contains everything.  All I am asking is whether my command above will guarantee that both repos contain the same info, or is there more to it?  If I have the same branches and stashes, is that all?

Comment: To make this clearer, I have a number of branches, B1, B2, B3, B4.  In order to make sure both computers are synced, I have to manually check each branch individually.  If I forget to check and I overwrite one repo with another, data will be lost.  I need a way to verify the whole repo, not just the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's rather straightforward.

Suppose you have repos *cloneA* and *cloneB* originally cloned from the same shared repo.

1. From within *cloneA* add the other clone as a new remote:

   `$ git remote add cloneB file:///path/to/cloneB/.git`
2. Then just fetch from it:

   `$ git fetch cloneB`

This will copy **all** branches that exist only in *cloneB* over to *cloneA* with all the corresponding commits and objects, so techinally _cloneA can now be discarded. Don't remove the remote ref though since that will make it much harder to locate the copied over branches.

This does *not* copy any stashes though. However, if you need to copy the stashes as well you can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository/5248758#5248758) approach.

Comment: I did not know that fetch would copy *all* remote branches, since a push command does not push all branches.  This is a good method, because it ensures that the other repo's contents do indeed get copied over.  I still need to check for stashes, however.

Comment: The "EXAMPLES" section in of my `git fetch` documentation states that:

"`$ git fetch origin` command copies _all_ branches from the remote refs/heads/ namespace and stores them to the local refs/remotes/origin/ namespace, unless the branch.<name>.fetch option is used to specify a non-default refspec. This also corresponds with my experience and a little test I performed before posting."

As to the stashes AFAIK is does _not_ copy them. But since stashes are actually commits too I usually just set branch pointers to the ones I need beforehand.

Comment: @user2730226, edited the answser to add a link about copying stashes