# Does each branch have a separate stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

If I am in a branch e.g. `test` and have some work. If I do a `git stash` and switch to `master` branch, if I do a `git stash clear` do I lose the work I saved in `test`? Or does each branch have a separate stash stack?

Answer (score 11):

No. Stashes are infact the reflog of a *reference* (sort of like a 'hidden branch', if you will): `refs/stash`

So,

- `git reflog refs/stash`

  ```
  e41a1b8 refs/stash@{0}: WIP on master: 42092ec PoC
  ```

  is roughly equivalent to

  `git stash list`

  ```
  stash@{0}: WIP on master: 42092ec PoC
  ```

So there's only one "branch" containing all stashes.

- The machinery might become more clear in this answer: [Is it possible to push a git stash to a remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository/5248758#5248758)
- you can 'deduce' what branch the stash fits onto by doing, e.g.

  ```
  git branch -a --contains stash@{0}^
  ```

  (asking: what branches contain the parent revision for this stash?)

Comment: As you suggested with the quotes around "branch" in the middle, `refs/stash` is not really a branch per se.  (It *is* a reference, just as branches and tags are references; but so are notes.)  `git stash branch ...` will let you change any given stash *into* a branch, though (by checking out the parent and then creating the new branch and applying the stash).  So if you have a stash and decide it should become a branch, that's easy to do.

Comment: @torek thanks for that addition. Would you believe I somehow always overlooked `git stash branch` :) Or perhaps my use of git predates that subcommand (?). Anyways, glad to have learned that.