# Recover uncommitted stashed changes

Tags: git, bitbucket

I accidentally deleted my .git folder after stashing major changes. I cannot recover my folder or my stashes. Is there any way I could recover the stashes from the server end(I am using bitbucket)?

Comment: No. Stashes do not get pushed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository

Comment: Thanks..Guess am doomed for this one :(

Comment: I'm sorry. You'll have to redo that. But often that's a valuable experience. I can write a song about the many times that git happens :D

Answer (score 3):

The `stashes` is stored in `./.git/refs/stash` while older ones are in the reflog of that ref in same `directory`.

**So, you cannot get those stashed changes back**

**Here is the documentation:**

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working
>   directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working
>   directory. The command saves your **`local modifications`** away and reverts
>   the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

It clearly mentions the `local modifications` so they are not even pushed.

You either need to restore that `.git` folder using `some ways` or you need do do them `again`