# Is it possible to specify new local git repository location for existing config?

Tags: git, git-init

By default, I typically run `git init` and have the local repository in the root directory. I store and work with my project files on a small-ish SSD but have a BIG ol' SATA HD on the same machine not doing much. I was thinking I should get into the practice of using it for the actual repositories for each project.

**EDIT:**

By this I mean I have the directory structure:

SMALL-DRIVE > My Project > .git > repository files...
SMALL-DRIVE > My Project > src > dev files...

and while I'd like the keep the 2nd one as is, I want to move the 1st one to

BIG-DRIVE > repositories > My Project > .git > repository files...
(or something similar)

Everything is staying on the same machine and there would be no change to the remote repository that I push to.

I **believe** I can pass `git init` this new path for new projects (pretty sure I can figure that out on my own), but is there a way to update an existing config to use the new path? And if so, is there a command that will move the current files in the repository or would I just manually move the .git directory?

Comment: I don't think I worded my initial question clearly. i basically want to store the local repository files in a different directory (on a different drive... to take advantage of the extra space) than the project's root directory. See **EDIT** in original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] is there a way to update an existing config to use the new path?

If I understand your question correctly, you currently have a repo on a small but fast HD, and you'd like to

- move the repo's `.git` directory to a big & slow HD,
- yet keep the repo's *working tree* on the small & fast HD.

Am I right?

In that case, `git init --separate-git-dir` is right up your alley. Quoting [`git init`'s man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt):

> `--separate-git-dir=<git dir>`
> Instead of initializing the repository as a directory to either `$GIT_DIR` or `./.git/`, create a text file there containing the path to the actual repository. This file acts as filesystem-agnostic Git symbolic link to the repository.
>
> If this is reinitialization, the repository will be moved to the specified path.

So, simply `cd` to your repo, and then run

```
git init --separate-git-dir <desired-location-on-big-and-slow-drive>
```

---

> I **believe** I can pass `git init` this new path for new projects [...]

Correct. Use the same command as above.

Comment: @juobs - regarding the last section of your answer, everything **is** on the small/fast drive. I want to keep doing my development there but store the repository files on the big/slow-ish drive.

Comment: @Daveh0 Ah yes. I misunderstood your question. Let me amend my answer...

Comment: @jubos - yup, that's exactly what I'm going for. Thanks!! I'll give `separate-git-dir `a try in a bit.

Comment: @jubobs, GJ on understanding exactly what the OP wanted! I don't know about him, but you got my upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

**Option 1 (Preferred): Mirroring**

Just run these commands to mirror a repository:

```
git clone --mirror git@example.com/upstream-repository.git
cd upstream-repository.git
git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git
```

*See more about mirroring [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/)*

**Option 2: Manual clone & push**

First step is to `git clone` the repository to a local directory.

Then, you add a new remote repository using `git remote add <name> <url>`

Then, you can simply `git push <name> --all` to send everything there

Comment: That's a good trick to know, but cloning will not retain everything (reflog, stashes, etc.).

Comment: @jubobs, stashes are local entities, so I don't think we should consider them as part of the clone. About reflogs, I actually don't know... That's a good question.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I don't think the OP wants to leave anything behind; if so, stashes should not get lost.

Comment: @jubobs, I don't think the OP pushed his stashes to the remote repository, so there is no need in copying them. If you want to get a sense of what you need to do to push a stash, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to push or clone his/her original repo.

Answer (score 0):

## Add a New Remote git to your Git Repo

git remote add origin git@yourgit.repo

## Verify new remote repo

git remote -v